# fso.GetFileName from a cell value instead of a direct path

Tags: excel, vba

i've been wondering if there's a way to to use the "GetFileName" to get the name from a path that exists in a cell instead of using a direct path eg below

`Filename = fso.GetFileName(Worksheets("Setup").Cells(8, 2).Value)`
instead of

```
FileName = FSO.GetFileName("C:\ExamplePath\ExampleFile.xls")
```

Thank you in advance for any hints

Comment: Did you try that?  did it not work?

Comment: yes i did try Filename = fso.GetFileName(Worksheets("Setup").Cells(8, 2).Value) but it gives me an error unlike if I use a direct path

Comment: "an error" is not very descriptive - what error do you get?  Does B2 have a full path ?

Comment: subscript out of range error

Comment: There's no worksheet with tab name "Setup" in the ActiveWorkbook.  If you want to reference some other workbook you need to specify that.

Comment: Thank you so much it was indeed the problem.